# facebook ios url types issue

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm a beginner in the iOS (native) world, I have a strange issue with the Facebook authentication in my demo app.

I've configured the .plist file with the following keys following the tutorial:

- `FacebbokAppID: <myappid>`
- `FacebookDisplayName: a name`
- `Url types (array)`

  - `Item 0 (dictionary)`

    - `Url Schemes (Array)`

      - `Item 0 (String): fb<myappid>`

Where `<myappid>` is the numerical app id of the registered app on the facebook website.
Now, I perform the login using this code:

```
- (void) facebookLoginLogout
{
// If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
  || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

// Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
// The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

// If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
} else {
// Open a session showing the user the login UI
// You must ALWAYS ask for basic_info permissions when opening a session
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"friends_online_presence"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

   // Retrieve the app delegate
   AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
   [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
}
}
```

And I've defined the method to handle state changes:

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{
  NSLog(@"here?");
  [..]
}
```

The problem is exactly that this method is never called in this situation.

**THE STRANGE POINT** is that, if I change `Url types -> Item 0 -> Url Schemes -> Item 0` value to something different, the method is called!

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can delete Url Schemes array from .Plist and it's works fine..

Comment: Ok, but I don't get the point because Facebook defines this value in this way: "This is used to ensure the application will receive the callback URL of the web-based OAuth flow." [ref](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/).

Comment: Url Schemes are used for Navigate from other Apps to your app.they use while import data from third party apps.

Comment: Ok thanks, this makes sense :) But still it doesn't explain why with that value set to fb<app_id> it doesn't work. Maybe it's related to the fact that I'm working on the simulator? I don't know, just trying to find a motivation.

Comment: ok,tell me while you tap on login Button,will it open in popup screen or in Facebook app?

Comment: in the popup screen, the facebook app is not installed on the simulator so it opens in the browser